# How to format the start and end time in iOS URL schemes in Shortcuts

Tags: ios, url, url-scheme, iso8601, ios-shortcut

I created a shortcut 'Add New Event' on my iPad. I need to automate the start and end time, so I use the iOS shortcuts URL schemes. I asign date variable to the start time and end time. Here's the URL I wrote for a start time 2024-01-01-06:00:00 and end time 2024-01-01-07:00:00

shortcuts://run-shortcut?name=Addevent&input=2024-01-01T06:00:00

I can't figure out how to properly write the end time so the URL will get me open the iOS calendar to create an event with a specified start and end time.

I wanted to attach an image of the shortcut I created on iPad, but it won't allow me. You can view the image here.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PIVAjg9Cta2SQr7eUMEpBSrZJpORVaMK/view?usp=sharing

note: I actually just need the end time an hour later than the start time. so if there's a better solution, please feel free to comment.